# Java Program using list ,set, database(Cricket Management System)

Tags: java, list, random, enums, set

My problem lies with the 5th function. I'm not getting how to solve it. Could someone help me?

1. populate from the database and store in the list.
   `List<Player>populate() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException;`
2. sort the list according to runs (highest first).
   `void sortRuns(List<Player> list);`
3. sort the list according to debut date.
   `void sortByDebut(List<Player> list);`
4. calculate the average of each player and return a list which has field average. The return list should be sorted according to average (highest first).
   `List<Player>sortByAverage(List<Player>list);`
5. return the set of players who have runs less than 10000. For example if you pass 3 to the function, it should return only 3 players randomly and each time a different set 
   should be generated.
   `Set<Player> randomSet(List<Player> list,int n);`

Beans Classes are:

```
public class Player{
    int capid;
    String playerName;
    Country country;
    int matches;
    int runs;
    Date Debut;
    int notOut;
    float average;
}
```

Country As enum:

```
public enum Country {
    India,Australia,SouthAfrica,NewZeland,England,SriLanka,WestIndies
}
```

---

```
Above Solved 4 functions are:

public class DataManagerImpl implements DataManager 
{
DBConnectionImpl dm=new DBConnectionImpl();
Connection conn;

@Override
public List<Player> populate() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    List<Player> list=new ArrayList<Player>();
    conn=dm.getConnection();
    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from stats");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Player p=new      Player(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),Country.valueOf(rs.getString(3)),rs.getInt(4),rs.getInt    (5),rs.getDate(6),rs.getInt(7));                                                
        list.add(p);
     }
    return list;
}


@Override
public void sortRuns(List<Player> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Player>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Integer.compare(o2.getRuns(),o1.getRuns());
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void sortByDebut(List<Player> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Player>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.getDebut().compareTo(o2.getDebut());
        }

    });
}

@Override
public List<Player> sortByAverage(List<Player> list) {

    List<Player> plist=new ArrayList<Player>();
    float average;
    for(Player p:list)
    {
        int runs=p.getRuns();
        int matchs=p.getMatches();
        average=(runs/matchs);
        p.setAverage(average);
        plist.add(p);

    }
    Collections.sort(plist,new Comparator<Player>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Double.compare(o2.getAverage(),o1.getAverage());
        }

    });
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return plist;
}
```

Comment: I edited your question so it is easier to read. Now however you may want to edit the question add some code of your own, so that others can see what you did to solve the other 4 questions and how you intend to solve 5. If you need help solving 5, try explaining what you don't "get". Don't you understand the question or don't you know how to solve a specific problem in the function (maybe the random is troublesome..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I understand the problem. *This will probably not run, but should give you an idea how to do it.*

```
Set<Player> randomSet(List<Player> list,int n){

    ArrayList<Player> possiblePlayers = new ArrayList<>();   // fist we create a list where we can put all players that have 10000 runs

    for(Player player: list){             // we loop through the list 
        if(player.getRuns()> 10000){      // check each player if he had more than 10000 runs
            possiblePlayers.add(player);   // and if so, we add him to our list of possible results
        }
    }

    // at this point we have a list of players that have more than 10000 runs and we need to randomly select a player and put him into the new Set

    // so first we create a Set that we can return
    Set<Player> resultSet = new HashSet<>();  // Set is abstract and needs an implemented class like HashSet. This may not be the most appropriate implementation for your case, but it will do for now.

     // now we need to pick n random players from our list. So we actually generate n numbers that we use as indexes

    Random random = new Random();   // first we instantiate our random generator
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();  // we will use this list to store the generated indexes, so we can check that we don't pick the same index twice


    while (n > 0) {
        Integer randomIndex = random.nextInt(possiblePlayers.size());  // first we pick a number between 0 and the size of our possiblePlayers list
        if (!indexes.contains(randomIndex)) {   // then we check if that number is already in the indexes list
            indexes.add(randomIndex);  // if not, we add it 
            n--;  // and decrement n;
        }
         // if the random number where already in the indexes list, the loop would simply continue and try again
    }

    // here we have now a lost of randomly generated (and unique) indexes
    // now we get the players at that indexes and put them in the result set

    for(Integer index: indexes){
       resultSet.add(possiblePlayers.get(index));
    }

    // and finally return the set
    return resultSet;          
}
```

As I said before, I am not sure if this method runs without errors. (I did not test it). It does however give you a solution. No guarantee that it is a good solution, though :) As you can see there are quite a lot of lists and Objects that are created, for such a small task. And I see a lot of potential to make it more efficient.